# Reading the value of variable in another if condition inside function

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have function defined for getting the data from JSON and passing it in render. But I had to put 2 different condition to process the data.

Below is the function:

```
filterItems = () => {
 let result = [];
 const { searchInput } = this.state;
 const filterbrandsnew = this.props.tvfilter.brand;
 if (filterbrandsnew) {
 let value = filterbrandsnew[0].options.map(({catgeory_name})=>catgeory_name);
 console.log (value);
 }
 const brand = value;
 if (searchInput) {
    result = this.elementContainsSearchString(searchInput, brand);
 } else {
    result = brand || [];
 }
 return result;
}
```

I want to have the value in this const `const brand = value;`

**Accessing the data in render method like below:**

```
render() {
const filteredList = this.filterItems();
return (
            <div className="filter-options">
                <ul className="languages">
                    {filteredList.map(lang => (
                        <li
                            className={lang === this.props.selectedLanguage ? 'selected' : ''}
                            onClick={this.props.onSelect.bind(null, lang)}
                            key={lang}
                        >
                            {lang}
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
}
```

Comment: you are asking how you can assign `const brand = value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example

```
if (filterbrandsnew) {
 let value = filterbrandsnew[0].options.map(({catgeory_name})=>catgeory_name);
 console.log (value);
}
```

code inside `if` statement creates a separate scope, which means any variables defined inside it can not be accessed in outer scope. 
What you could do is move `value` variable definition to outer scope

```
let value
if (filterbrandsnew) {
 value = filterbrandsnew[0].options.map(({catgeory_name})=>catgeory_name);
 console.log (value);
}
```

This way `value` will either contain `undefined` if it never entered an `if` statement, or a result you need if it did.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `value` outside of `if` block

```
filterItems = () => {
 let result = [];
 const { searchInput } = this.state;
 const filterbrandsnew = this.props.tvfilter.brand;
 let value;
 if (filterbrandsnew) {
    value = filterbrandsnew[0].options.map(({catgeory_name})=>catgeory_name);
    console.log (value);
 }
 const brand = value;
 if (searchInput) {
    result = this.elementContainsSearchString(searchInput, brand);
 } else {
    result = brand || [];
 }
 return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the describable additional data to your function return payload

JSON data function:

```
filterItems = () => {
 ...
 return { items: result, brand: value };
}
```

Render function:

```
render() {
const filteredHandler = this.filterItems();
const filteredList = filteredHandler.items;
const brand = filteredHandler.brand;
...
```